# Is there a way to add a custom background colour and data colour for each circle in the ProgressChart of react-native-chart-kit?

Tags: react-native, react-native-chart-kit

This is my ProgressChart

```
 const chartConfig = {
    backgroundGradientToOpacity: 0.5,
    color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(26, 255, 146, ${opacity})`,
  };
 <ProgressChart
    data={graphData}
    height={220}
    width={300}
    chartConfig={chartConfig}
/>
```

[image]

This is my graph data

```
{"background": ["#A7FFA7", "#EFEF8C", "#F39A9A"], "color": ["#007F14", "#9BB500", "#A20D00"], "data": [0.1, 0.1, 0.2], "labels": ["WELL-SPENT", "RECREATION", "UNPRODUCTIVE"]}
```

[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/indiespirit/react-native-chart-kit/issues/684)
[React Native Chart Kit: Progress Ring](https://github.com/indiespirit/react-native-chart-kit#progress-ring)

I tried this but it just fills in the colour and I'm not able to differentiate bw the background and data of the circle.

```
const chartConfig = {
    backgroundGradientToOpacity: 0.5,
   color: (opacity = 1, index) => graphData.color[index],
  };
```

[image]